# Cant understand how return works in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, async-await, return

Have trouble with app logic.
So I have function to login

```
 async login() {
        debug('USERNAME: ', ITEM.USERNAME, 'PASSWORD: ', ITEM.PASSWORD);
        API.state.proxyUrl = genProxyString();
        debug('Proxy: ', API.state.proxyUrl);

        try {
            debug('Login');
            await API.execute(AccountLoginCommand, {
                username: ITEM.USERNAME,
                password: ITEM.PASSWORD,
            });
            ITEM.USER = await API.account.currentUser();
            debug(ITEM.USER);
            return ITEM.USER;
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
}
```

Usage

```
(async () => {
    await login();
    await doStuff();
})();
```

doStuff() funtion doesnt happens after login() but ITEM.USER outputs into console.

Comment: It may help to add your `doStuff` function code to the question.

Comment: doStuff() just console logs "It works"

Comment: Based on what you posted, it does seem like it should work. Could you try to use an [executable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) to get an example that replicates your error so we can better debug it?

Comment: I have no idea why but yeah it started to work

Answer (score 0):

If `ITEM.USER` returns then that means that async/await is working perfectly fine. However, you should make sure that you are returning something in your `doStuff()` function.